# produce a grid of geographic coordinates within 1 mile of each other with QGIS or PostGIS

Tags: coordinates, vector-grid

For a given county (bounded box, lets say), I need to get a network of gps points such that each point is 1 mile from its nearest neighbor point in each cardinal direction. The result of this initial calculation would be an array of gps coordinates, which if displayed on a map would look like the vertices on a piece of graph paper.

With the one mile radius requirement, this process is arduous by hand for reasonably sized areas..

I'm using an API that takes point data combined with a buffer radius value to find locations. The plan is to make the buffer radii something like 0.7 miles in order to ensure 100% saturation of a given area.

Comment: What software are you using? Should the resulting points be aligned with anything (e.g. the first point should lie on the north west corner of the county, or the points should coincide with the map grid)?

Comment: I wonder about the references to "gps" in this question: are you saying you actually want to take a GPS unit out into the field, place it at each vertex of such a grid, and obtain a reading? Or place a station for differential correction?  Or what?

Comment: @Jake The points should be aligned with one another, that's about it.

Comment: @whuber I absent-mindedly used "gps points", simply meaning little arrays of lat/lon floats viz. "gps coordinates

Comment: @Jake Just edited question title to answer yours. Good call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QGIS has a vector operator 'regular points'.

Go to 'Vector', 'Research tools', 'Regular Points'.

As an additional point, you can easily generate grids (even hexagon grids!) with the MMQGIS plugin for QGIS 2.0.

[image: MMQGIS]